# Not able to get deleted character from UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, range, uitextview

I am trying to retrieve the deleted character from UITextView when user presses delete button on keypad.

When I enter some text in textview for eg:(abc), I am able to retrieve the deleted character by checking the range and location. So no problem for english text

The challenge starts when I have a non english text, for eg "Hindi" language.

Lets say i entered "परक" in textview, and then if I delete one character at a time from right to left, I am able to identify the deleted character as क, र, प respectively.

The real problem start when I have Hindi vowels in the string

For eg: If i have a text as "परी". Then according to Hindi text it contains three characters as प, र, ी. Here ी is a long vowel in Hindi language

When i enter ी in textview, the delegate method is able to identify this text.

However when i press delete button on keyboard to delete ी from word "परी", the range calculation to determine which word is deleted seems to go wrong. 
I get range value to delete ी as

Range(3..<3)
  - startIndex : 3
  - endIndex : 3

Since startIndex and endIndex are same, I get an empty string.

Following is the code I am using to enter or delete a character in textview

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if ( range.location == 0 && text == " " )
    {
        return false
    }

    // Its backspace
    if text == ""
    {
        // Set startIndex for Range
        let startIndex = textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location, limit: textView.text.endIndex)

        // Set new Range
        let newRange = startIndex..<textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location + range.length, limit: textView.text.endIndex)

        // Get substring
        // Here I get the character that is about to be deleted
        let substring = textView.text[newRange]

        print(substring) //Gives empty string when i delete  ी

        return true
    }

    print(text) // This prints  ी when i enter it in textview  after पर
    return true
}
```

It would be great if anyone can help me with this. I have checked with Android and it is able to identify ी, when deleted. 
Awaiting for replies curiously....

Note: Code is written in Swift 2.3

Comment: Is it the uncode problem? can you try once converting the string to fixed unicode and then comparing the range ?

Comment: What is the value of the `range` received by parameter? I don't know about Hindi characters, but in a Swift Playground, both `"परी".characters.count` and `"पर".characters.count` return `2`... However, `"परी".lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)` is `9` and `"पर".lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)` is `6`. Seems to be a problem on how you are handling UNICODE strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I removed the last character of `"परी"` in a `UITextView`, I got `NSRange(location: 2, length: 1)` in the delegate method. It's not empty, as you see, its length is not 0.

The problem is that your code of retrieving the `substring` is completely wrong.

When an iOS API returns an `NSRange` for string related operations, its `location` and `length` are based on UTF-16, which is the basis of `NSString`. You should not use those values for `characters` (`String.CharacterView`) based index calculation.

Replace these lines of your code:

```
    // Set startIndex for Range
    let startIndex = textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location, limit: textView.text.endIndex)

    // Set new Range
    let newRange = startIndex..<textView.text.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location + range.length, limit: textView.text.endIndex)

    // Get substring
    // Here I get the character that is about to be deleted
    let substring = textView.text[newRange]
```

To:

```
        //### Get substring
        let substring = (textView.text as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
```

Your code seems to be written in Swift 2, but in Swift 3, it becomes:

```
        //### Get substring
        let substring = (textView.text as NSString).substring(with: range)
```